# General question about new objective function W using the simplex method

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, two-phase-simplex

In regards to the two-phase simplex method; When creating a new objective function that consists the sum of the constraint(s) with artificial variables, I am told that if the Min value of (wmin) w is >0 it is infeasible and when w(min)=0 we can discard w and move onto phase 2. However what if w(min)<0? I found this to be the case when trying to solve

```
Maximise: z=x1+x2
Subject to: x2<=8
           -x1+x2>=-4
            x1+x2<=12
```

Comment: Then show the steps till your case came up.

Answer (score 0):

In the first phase of the two-phase method, we add **non-negative** artificial variables, so $w_{min} < 0$ is **impossible**.  Your example *can't* illustrate the problem that you raised.

I'll *modify* your sample LPP so that I can answer your question about the two-phase method by **giving you the motivation to add $w$**.  You may skip the next section to my modified problem.

### Your LPP

To find a basic feasible solution to your problem, we transform it into the standard form.

\begin{array}{ccccc}
\max &z=&x_1&+x_2 & \\
\text{s.t.}& & & \phantom{+}x_2 &\le 8 \\
& & -x_1&+x_2&\ge-4 \\
& & x_1&+x_2&\le12 \\
\end{array}

Note that the slack/surplus variables $s_1,s_2,s_3$ are **non-negative**.

\begin{array}{ccclc}
\max &z=&x_1&+x_2 & \\
\text{s.t.}& & & \phantom{+}x_2 + s_1 &= 8 \\
& & -x_1&+x_2 - s_2&=-4 \\
& & x_1&+x_2+s_3&= 12 \\
& & & s_1,s_2,s_3 &\ge 0
\end{array}

We'll have no difficulty in writing the simplex tableau of this problem.

\begin{array}{ccclc}
\max &z=&x_1&+x_2 & \\
\text{s.t.}& & & \phantom{+}x_2 + s_1 &= 8 \\
& & x_1&-x_2 + s_2&=4 \\
& & x_1&+x_2+s_3&= 12 \\
& & & s_1,s_2,s_3 &\ge 0
\end{array}

\begin{array}{rrrrrr|l}
               & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 &    \\ \hline
           s_1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  8 \\
           s_2 &   1 &  -1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &  4 \\
           s_3 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 & 12 \\ \hline
               &  -1 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  0 \\
\end{array}

We see that $(s_1,s_2,s_3)=(8,4,12)$ is a basic feasible solution, so the two-phase method is *not* needed.  That why callculus asks you to show the steps.

### Modified LPP

To let you see that why $w_{min}<0$ is **impossible**, I changed the '$\ge$' sign in the second constraint to '$\le$'.

\begin{array}{ccccc}
\max &z=&x_1&+x_2 & \\
\text{s.t.}& & & \phantom{+}x_2 &\le 8 \\
& & -x_1&+x_2&\color{red}{\le}-4 \\
& & x_1&+x_2&\le12 \\
\label{LPP}
\tag{*}
\end{array}

To apply the simplex algorithm, we first need a basic feasible solution, which is difficult to guess especially for LPP having lots of decision variables and constraints.  Thus, we add slack/surplus variables and transform all inequalities into equalities to make it easier.

\begin{array}{cccll}
\color{grey}{\max} &\color{grey}{z=}&\color{grey}{x_1}&\color{grey}{+x_2} & \text{we don't care about this}\\
\text{s.t.}& & & \phantom{+}x_2 + s_1 &= 8 \\
& & -x_1&+x_2 + s_2&=-4 \\
& & x_1&+x_2+s_3&= 12 \\
& & & s_1,s_2,s_3 &\ge 0
\end{array}

#### Why add $w$, and why $w$ need to be non-negative?

Since in the first phase, we aim at finding a feasible solution to the LPP, we don't care about the optimality.  If we *dropped* the last constraint $s_1,s_2,s_3\ge0$, the most obvious solution would be $x_1=x_2=0$, $s_1=8$, $\color{red}{s_2=-4}$, $s_3=12$.  (I used past sentence here like "If I *were* you, ..." to indicate the impossibility of the condition.)

(For a computer,) a possible way to get a feasible solution is to add an (**non-negative**) artificial variable $w(=4)$ to the second constraint, then use pivot operations (something that a machine can do) to reduced it to $w=0$ (so that $w$ vanishes).

\begin{array}{cccll}
\color{grey}{\max} &\color{grey}{z=}&\color{grey}{x_1}&\color{grey}{+x_2} & \text{we don't care about this}\\
\text{s.t.}& & & \phantom{+}x_2 + s_1 &= 8 \\
& & x_1&-x_2 - s_2 \color{red}{+w}&=4 \\
& & x_1&+x_2+s_3&= 12 \\
& & & s_1,s_2,s_3 \color{red}{,w} &\ge 0
\end{array}

Initially, $w=4$, and we try to make $w=0$.  (i.e. "*minimize*" $w$).

\begin{array}{cccll}
\min &z=&\color{red}w& & \text{we do care this}\\
\text{s.t.}& & & \phantom{+}x_2 + s_1 &= 8 \\
& & x_1&-x_2 - s_2 \color{red}{+w}&=4 \\
& & x_1&+x_2+s_3&= 12 \\
& & & s_1,s_2,s_3 \color{red}{,w} &\ge 0
\end{array}

To let others understand that how the $w$ can be discarded when it equals zero, I'll do the pivot operations here.

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr|l}
        & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 &  w &    \\ \hline
    s_1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  0 &  8 \\
      w &   1 &  -1 &   0 &  -1 &   0 &  1 &  4 \\
    s_3 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &  0 & 12 \\ \hline
        &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & -1 &  0 \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Make it a simplex tableau.

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr|l}
        & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 &  w &    \\ \hline
    s_1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  0 &  8 \\
      w & 1^* &  -1 &   0 &  -1 &   0 &  1 &  4 \\
    s_3 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &  0 & 12 \\ \hline
        &   1 &  -1 &   0 &  -1 &   0 &  0 &  4 \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr|l}
        & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 &  w &    \\ \hline
    s_1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  0 &  8 \\
    x_1 &   1 &  -1 &   0 &  -1 &   0 &  1 &  4 \\
    s_3 &   0 &   2 &   0 &   2 &   1 & -1 &  8 \\ \hline
        &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & -1 &  0 \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Therefore, $(x_1,x_2,s_1,s_2,s_3)=(4,0,8,0,8)$ is a basic feasible solution to the original LPP $\eqref{LPP}$.  Here, $w=0$ can be discarded.  In fact, in the last simplex tableau, the column $w$ can be *omitted* since it will never enter the basis again.

Now, it is clear why $w_{min} > 0$ implies that the feasible region is empty.